# A more modern textbook on Axiomatic Set Theory, at the same level of rigor as Suppes?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

I'm currently using Suppes textbook to learn axiomatic set theory. Is there a more modern textbook that is just as well-written? I'm thinking of a textbook that still has a treatment of urelements (for example), but is modern enough that the empty set isn't denoted by 0. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can just put a line through "$0$" to make it "$\phi$."  Just kidding.  Calling the empty set $0$ would annoy me too.

Answer (score 0):

Though I actually prefer older books to some extent (my favorites on my shelf are Quine, Rosser, Cohen, and Suppes), one newer book I quite enjoyed was Smullyan and Fitting's *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem*. It's reasonably sized, available from Dover, and, unlike older introductory texts, actually deals with forcing in its later chapters.

The only real caveat I'd offer is that the treatment of forcing is a little unusual in that much of the exposition explicitly uses the modal logic S4 (which it does contain an introduction to), and describes the forcing construction as the building of an S4 model. However, if you can run with it, it's actually a conceptually rewarding way to view forcing.

Comment: Oh, though this book does *not* still include discussion of urelements. However, it is a good prep for diving into some of the heavier books that do revisit urelements by in the context of Fraenkel-Mostowski models.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs by K.Kunen. Although it does not cover ur-elements. It's almost entirely on ZF and ZFC. And I get lost in the details in the def'n of Godel's constructable class L. For an easy and useful def'n of L, I suggest the essay in the book Lectures In Set Theory (various authors: edited by Morley).